# When does a subprocess.PIPE will close?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

Firstly my problem is:

After I write some string to `p1.stdin`. I  see nothing in `test`file.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen('cat ', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen('cat ', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=open("test", 'w'), shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
p1.stdin.write('asda'*100)
```

Then I got the answer from `stackoverflow`.

The reason is that the default paramenter of `bufsize` is `-1`, which means this is a `buffered` IOWrapper.And I need  to make the text existed in `p1.stdin`.

So the solution is: `p1.stdin.flush()` or  `p1.stdin.close()` or`p1.communicate()`

I find that `p2` need to read from an `opened` file-like object(`p1.stdout`) and `p1.stdout` is closed after I used `p1.communicate()` or `p1.stdin.close()`.

My question is :
When will `p1.stdout` be closed and 
If it's possible that some data still remained in `p1.stdout` and p2 never get the chance to read it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the first child processes its input data. The `cat` program (I assume it is `/bin/cat`) ensures that it will read stdin until end of file, and write everything it could read on stdout before exiting unless it receives a signal.

Here there is no problem and a `p1.stdin.close()` will cleanly close both childs after everything has been written to the `test` file.

But `p1.stdin.flush()` is likely to have no effect. It will just ensures that all the data have been passed from Python to the `p1` child. But `/bin/cat` buffers its output when it is not connected to a terminal, which is the case here because it is connected to a pipe. So `p2` will not receive anything until the output buffer of `cat` in `p1` is full or `p1` stdin is closed.

Comment: You mean there is a buffer which is handled by cat program?

Comment: When does the subprocess p1 terminate  and Who controls the closing of p1.stdin and p1.stdout.

Comment: @BAKEZQ: `/bin/cat` is a C program and is uses buffered io. `p1` will terminate as soon at it will find an end of file on its stdin and it will have write everything on its stdout.

Comment: How about p1.stdout. If this ubprocess close p1.stdout as soon as he just writed every data into stdout. Then p2 will lose this part of data.

Comment: @BAKEZQ: No. `p2` will only see an end of file after it will have read every byte  from the pipe, so after reading everything. Then again it will write everything to its own stdout (here the `test` file) and only then exit.